# How do I select rows in a MySQL table by column/field value?

Tags: php, mysql

i have table called messages which has field called (emails) with type text .
for example this field value is (email@domain.com , example@any.net . notme@yahoo.com , me@yahoo.com).
and what i want when i am logged in with (me@yahoo.com) to display only messages that has value of (me@yahoo.com).
how can it be done with mysql & php ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE EMAIL = 'me@yahoo.com';
```

but EMAIL should probably be indexed to avoid haveing to scan the whole table to find matching rows. And type `TEXT` is probably unnecessary. Emails are not likely to be longer than 100 characters, so maybe set the type to `VARCHAR(100)` or similar.

Or given that each user will have an id, it's perhaps better get them out by USER_ID (which should also be indexed):

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE USER_ID = ?;
```

where USER_ID is the ID in your USER table or equivalent.

Comment: thanks Richard ,
but my idea is to avoid building another table to hold users id and the message which depend on relation one to many ,
so i thought there would be way with this idea .